# "UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate" swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional

Tags: swift, appdelegate

Trying to access my AppDelegate instance but failed with swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    class func getInstance() -> AppDelegate {
        let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate;
        return delegate as AppDelegate;
    }
    ........
}
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: When are you calling `getInstance()`? Show the call in its context.

Comment: Also, _is_ AppDelegate the actual class of your app delegate?

Comment: Your code works perfectly when I run it. So you must be running it at the wrong time or on the wrong class. Or something. But no one knows what it is you are doing wrong until you provide the requested further info.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it's caused by Urbanairship library. When application is initialized, I called the api

```
    var uaconfig = UAConfig.defaultConfig() as UAConfig
    UAirship.setLogLevel(UALogLevel.Debug)
    UAirship.takeOff(uaconfig)
    UAPush.shared().userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    UAPush.shared().userPushNotificationsEnabled = true
```

After I removed code above, everything is fine now.